# Multi column overlay menu, how to base column number on number of items

Tags: css

So I have a left hand navigation system, lists categories. On mouse over, it displays sub categories in two columns. I'd like to change this so that if there are less than 8 sub categories it lists them in one column, if more than it will break them out into two columns. Here is my current code

```
#left-nav ul.level0 {
width:404px !important;
}

#left-nav UL LI.level1{
float:left !important;
width:200px;
margin:0 1px;
}

#left-nav UL LI, #left-nav UL LI.last{
background:none !important;

}

#left-nav UL LI.level1 UL{
float:left !important;
padding:1px;
}
```

Here is my modification that doesn't work...

```
#left-nav ul.level0 {
width:auto !important;
}

#left-nav ul.level0 nth-child(n+8) {
width:404px !important;
}


#left-nav UL LI.level1{
float:left !important;
width:200px;
margin:0 1px;
}

#left-nav UL LI, #left-nav UL LI.last{
background:none !important;

}

#left-nav UL LI.level1 UL{
float:left !important;
padding:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way to do this would be to use Flexbox.  However, not all browsers that support Flexbox support wrapping, so this currently only works in Chrome, Opera, and IE10 (Firefox is supposed to be adding support for it *soon*).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ccpb0u99

```
ul {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  line-height: 1.4;
  max-height: 11.2em; /* [num of items] * [line-height] */
}
```